# jQuery dynamic onchange function for select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to create a dynamic funktion in jQuery, which handles onchange event for a select (dropdown) and updates to other text fields with some calculated values.
But I'm having some trouble with.

My select is like this

```
<select name="r514b" id="r514b" size="1" class="listform" style="width: 155px;"> <option value="0">Vælg overfladebehandling</option> <?php while($farverow = mysql_fetch_array($farvequery, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { if ($res['r514b'] == $farverow['id']) {
        $r514bselected = "selected";
} else {
    $r514bselected = "";
}?> <option value="<?php echo $farverow['id']; ?>" <?php echo $r514bselected; ?> data-nypris="<?php echo $farverow['pris']; ?>" data-grundpris="<?php echo $farvegrundrow['pris']; ?>" data-sumvaegt="<?php echo $res['r477']; ?>" data-db="<?php echo $res['r502']; ?>"><?php echo $farverow['navn']; ?></option> <?php } ?> </select>
```

and the jQuery is like:

```
$('#r514b').change(function(){
    var ny_pris = $(this).find(':selected').data('nypris');
    var grundpris = $(this).find(':selected').data('grundpris');
    var sumVaegt = $(this).find(':selected').data('sumvaegt');
    var db = $(this).find(':selected').data('db')
    var overflade_forskel = ny_pris - grundpris;
    // alert(ny_pris);
  //  alert(grundpris);
  //  alert(sumVaegt); // * overflade_forskel);
    var pris_forskel = (sumVaegt * overflade_forskel)/(1-(ds.r502.value/100));
//    alert(pris_forskel);
    ds.id514d.value = Math.round(pris_forskel);
    ds.r514d.value = Math.round(pris_forskel);
});
```

The reason I want to make it dynamical is that I need to have multiple selects, which basically does the same thing. Only difference is which text fields they update. 
So I was hoping that I somehow to make the function catch the selects dynamic, and update the fields dynamic maybe from some extra data attributes on the selects.

But how do I do that?

Comment: Please, replace the php code by generated html output.

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library in the PHP? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: If all of your similar selects has the same `listform` class then you can just bind to that but I am unsure about your `ds.` values

Comment: Anyway if you want to have multiple selects (or any other element) all using the same event handler, a common way to do that is to give them all the same "class", and then pass that class as the selector to jQuery. e.g. `<select class="yourClass" id="s1" ... <select class="yourClass" id="s2"...` and `$(".yourClass").change(...`

Comment: Let's first get the mysql_ / mysqli out of the question. It's a entirely internal production system, and the resources to completely rewrite the system, haven't been given.
`ds.` is the form.
The class approach I'll have to look into. My problem is that many many other fields have the same class, but I only need this for around 4-7 selects. But I can create a new class for these select alone, which is identical of the original class.